# Zend Soap Server with .NET client - 'unknown error'

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework2

I have implemented a web service using Zend Soap Server.

Connecting to it using a PHP client (Zend Client) it works as expected. However with a .NET client it is returning the rather unhelpful error 'unknown error'.

Error log is showing:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /path/to/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 881
```

Has anyone come across this issue? Here is my server code:

```
public function server()
{
    // Soap Server options
    $options = array(
        'classmap' => array(
            'TransactionType' => 'Acme\TransactionType',
        ),
    );

    // Create Soap Server
    $server = new Server(public_path('file.wsdl'), $options);

    // Bind Class to Soap Server
    $server->setClass('Acme\Transaction');

    // Handle request
    $server->handle();

}

public function wsdl()
{
    // Output WSDL
    $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover(new ArrayOfTypeSequence());
    $autodiscover->setClass('Acme\Transaction')
                 ->setUri(\URL::route('server'))
                 ->setServiceName('AcmeTransactions');
    $wsdl = $autodiscover->generate();

    $wsdl->dump(public_path('file.wsdl'));
}
```

Acme/Transaction looks like this:

```
class Transaction extends \Eloquent
{

 /**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'transactions';

/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = array();

/**
 * Saves a TransactionType to the database.
 *
 * @param TransactionType $transaction
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function saveTransaction(TransactionType $transaction)
{
    /**
     * @var Transaction $model
     */
    $model = new self();
    $model->fill(
        array(
            'transaction_id'       => $transaction->transaction_id,
            'transaction_number'   => $transaction->transaction_number,
            // ...
        )
    );

    return $model->save();
}

}
```

Acme/TransactionType looks like this:

```
class TransactionType {

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $transaction_id = '';

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $transaction_number = '';

// ...

}
```

Comment: without any code snippet no one can help u. but in my own experience it was a datatype mismatch between php and .net.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the logs and it is showing `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /path/to/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 881` when trying to handle the Soap request.

Comment: it seems that ur server wants s string but the .net client is sending an array :D, whats the structure of 'Acme\Transaction' and how do you handle the service in the .net client?

Comment: I updated the question which shows the basic structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by making use of Zend\Soap\Server\DocumentLiteralWrapper.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.soap.server.html#document-literal-wsdl-handling

Moral of the story - if you are building a Zend Soap Server that needs to be consumed by C# clients check out document-literal-wsdl-handling to smooth out these kinds of cross-platform issues.